# C# need help getting variable into a method

Tags: c#, methods

I have 3 different variables that I am trying to use in other methods. I want to use the "retirementmoney" from the RunSpendinginRetirementModule in the RunSavingsRightNowModule. Can someone please show me how to do this? Thank you!

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    RunMenu();
    string choice = Console.ReadLine();

    if (choice == "1"){
      RunSpendinginRetirementModule();
    } 
    if (choice == "2"){
      RunSavingsRightNowModule();
    }
      else if (choice == "3"){
      RunSavingsNeededModule();
    }
  }

    public static void RunSpendinginRetirementModule() {
      Console.WriteLine("How much do you anuually spend");
      int annualspent = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      int retirementmoney = annualspent * 25;
      double retirementspent = retirementmoney * 0.03;
      Console.WriteLine("You will need {0} for retirement",retirementmoney);
      Console.WriteLine("You can spend {0} each year during retirement", retirementspent);
    }
    public static void RunSavingsRightNowModule(){
      Console.WriteLine("how much you are currently saving");
      Console.WriteLine("how much are you saving a month");
      double savingmonth = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      double savingyear = savingmonth * 12;
      Console.WriteLine("how old are you");
      int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      Console.WriteLine("at what age do you plan to retire");
      int retirementage = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      int savingsyears = retirementage - age;
      double retirementsavings = savingyear * savingsyears;
      Console.WriteLine("at the rate you are saving you will have {0} when you retire at age {1}", retirementsavings, retirementage);
    }

    public static void RunSavingsNeededModule(){

    }
    public static void RunMenu(){
      Console.WriteLine("Retirement Calculator");
      Console.WriteLine("1) Spending in Retirement");
      Console.WriteLine("2) Savings Right Now");
      Console.WriteLine("3) Savings needed");
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your methods are returning not value as they are declared as 'void'.
You need to change these to return a value, and then store this in your calling method.

I will show an example for one method:

```
//Change the return type from void to double
 public static double RunSpendinginRetirementModule() 
 {
      Console.WriteLine("How much do you anuually spend");
      int annualspent = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      int retirementmoney = annualspent * 25;
      double retirementspent = retirementmoney * 0.03;
      Console.WriteLine("You will need {0} for retirement",retirementmoney);
      Console.WriteLine("You can spend {0} each year during retirement", retirementspent);

     //now return the value
     return retirementspent;
    }
```

Then update your MainClass.  Again, I only show this for one method.

```
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    RunMenu();
    string choice = Console.ReadLine();

    //Declare new variable here, set default value of 0.0
    double retirementAmount = 0.0;

    if (choice == "1")
    {
      //Update call to receive return value
      retirementAmount = RunSpendinginRetirementModule();
    } 
    ...
```

You can do the same for your other methods.